# how to retrive the rss link which is in anchor tag?

Tags: java, android

```
public String getRSSLinkFromURL(String url) {

org.jsoup.select.Elements links;
    try {
        // Using JSoup library to parse the html source code
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();        
 // finding rss links which are having link[type=application/rss+xml]

 links = doc.select("link[type=application/rss+xml]");

        // check if urls found or not
        if (links.size() > 0 ) {
        rss_url = links.get(0).attr("href").toString();

    }
    }
     catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // returing RSS url
    return rss_url;
}
```

I am developing the android rss application .This is my code snippets.Here only the rss links which are in the link tag will be matched and retrieved. But the problem is some rss links which are in anchor tag can not be retrieved because it does not have any common attribute value. Do u have any other solutions. pls reply.

thank you..

Comment: Please post more detail so we can help you and tell what's wrong in your codes..

Comment: You may have a look this this question, which is similar.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357800/how-to-get-anchor-tag-link-from-a-url-java-android

Comment: i used the same method..using jsoap i can only retrive the rss link which has link tag with type attribute.. example <link type="application/rss+xml" but i need to know how to retrive the anchor tag which has rss link.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously don't know how people understood this question.

Please do mention your 
1) coding strategy
2) platform you are working(Is it android?? or just Java ???)
3) Are you using PHP??

You may try this :

```
   <WebView 
   android:id="@+id/web_view"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
```

In Java class file:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
   WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
   wb.loadDataWithBaseURL("", "<b> its html text </b>", mimeType, encoding, "");
   }
```